# What's the best counter strategy against battlecruisers?

Tags: starcraft-2

How should I prepare my army when attacking someone who has 12+ battlecruisers?
(Protoss/Zerg/Terran answers are more than appreciated)

Comment: 1 viking, over infinite time, can beat infinite battle cruisers if they don't have Yamato cannon.

Comment: A battlecruiser army will almost surely have Yamato cannons though.

Comment: @RodYan: Huh? infinite battle cruisers will obviously beat 1 viking over infinite time.. unless you mean that you could theoretically micro the viking for success? The viking does have 9 range and the battle cruiser only 6 I think.

Comment: That's exactly why it would work. Not only does viking have 9 range, it is also much faster.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unlike in Starcraft 1, the Starcraft 2 Battlecruiser is an over specialized unit.  It has high ground damage and a long charge up time on its Yamato gun (excellent reference to the [birth of anime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato) right there).  This combined with its slow speed give you a number of options to deal with it.  I'll try to break them down by strategy rather than unit composition (as you should never build a specific unit to counter).

### Zerg

The major Zerg strategies are as follows:

1. Melee Zerg - usually an effort to deal with a Mech heavy build, a late game switch to BC will punish this Zerg heavily.  As Melee Zerg revolves around using infestors to pin down mobile units these are going to be your work horse.  MC is nice, but Fungal Growth is going to be your key.  Try to pin them down and swing your army around them.  Their slow speed and tendency to bunch should mean you can take them out of the game.
2. Flying Zerg - Usually a muta harass strategy, you should see the BC long in advance or have Corruptors built to deal with air to air.  However, if you don't for some reason you'll want to abuse the Battlecruiser's slow speed.  Use hit and run tactics to string them out and then pick off members near the back.  If you're having trouble with this strat, throw up some Spore Crawlers to slow them down.  They won't do anything, but he'll take the time to kill them.
3. Missile Zerg - This is actually the hardest one (strangely enough) as Hydralisks die too quickly vs Battlecruisers.  You're going to have to use creep and fungal growth to keep the range advantage.  In a straight up fight you'll die so try to hit and run on creep.  Nydus Canal help here.
4. Queens - its worth noting that mass queen is an amazing counter to Battlecruisers as the ability to heal and high air dps make queens tough and force BC to rely on Yamato to get any kills.

### Protoss

The major Protoss strategies are as follows:

1. 4 gate - You should have High Templar by this time, if not default to the 3gate/Robo strategy. Templar feedback is useful (and you should use it), but the killer here is Psystorm.  Battlecruisers not only move slowly, they have very slow acceleration.  This means they'll be slow to respond to your storms.  With 2-3 Templar you should be able to blanket them and throw down more as they run.
2. Starport - Any Protoss air unit does well against Battlecruisers.  Phoenix shoot-and-scoot means you can stay out of range of running Battlecruisers, and their poor shooting method (rapid fire of low damage shots) means you will destroy them.  Voidrays are actually less effective as you have to stay facing them and charge up.  It isn't until you're fully charged that you'll be effective.  If you can draw them out, this should be fine, otherwise sacrifice a building to charge them up.
3. 3 gate/robo - This is the hardest point to counter from as you'll only have Stalkers which get squashed by BC.  Use your faster speed as best you can.  If you can get blink, use blink micro to force them to spread their damage out.  Don't blink in, this is a common mistake.  Instead a-move in and blink out.  Recharge your shields and attack as many times as possible.

### Terran

1. 3 Rax - A MMM strategy will be able to produce cheap Marines which are more cost effective than any other unit.  Even though they die faster, if you produce enough and constantly reinforce you should be fine.  Use the 3 point strategy to maximize your marine's lifespan. Watch this quick video of [Boxer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJp0t9n8DWk).  At the beginning you'll notice he spreads his marines out (here to reduce aoe from lurkers) he does this by taking a single control group and breaking it up into 3.  This provide the ability to make a very strong "Arc."  The result is he is able to bring more fire power to bay on the Lurkers than would otherwise be possible.  Use the same idea against Battlecruisers.  They'll be able to stack up for higher damage; forming an arc is your counter to this.
2. Mech - A Mech heavy build will naturally suffer against battle cruisers as your main defense is Thor which have little effect.  Supplement your Siege tanks with Missile Turrets with upgrades.  This will force him to kill the turrets while you remove your Siege.  Your main force though, will depend on Thors with heavy SCV reinforcement to take them out.  Where you can, add in Marines for high dps.  Marines are the most cost effective dps you have.
3. 1:1:1 - This strategy is so effective against Battlecruisers that its most likely he won't build them, but if by some strange change he does use your Vikings.  Vikings basically curb stomp Battlecruiser as they are everything the Battlecruiser is not: good vs air, long range, fast unit.  Hit them at long range then run back.  Since Battlecruiser shoots rapid fire weak shots, they should only get off 1 or 2, meaning you take minimal damage.  If you lose this then you need to practice.

Remember, you should never think: "What unit counters X?" but rather "How do I use what I have to win?"

Comment: WOW! The Protoss section is INCREDIBLY WRONG.

Comment: @Doug how is it wrong? Feedback on BC with a lot of energy combined with storms will tear right through them. Combined with stalkers/phoenix

Comment: Also, if they don't have a Raven, you can use hallucination with your Sentries and create a bunch of voidrays in addition to your army.  They don't do damage but if you play your cards right your opponent will be busy attacking hallucinations instead of your actual units while your army does the damage

Comment: @Mark I did leave out more sentry/raven based strategies.  There is no good reason I did this and I may add them in.  I think Doug believes Void Rays are the only answer for Protoss: see his answer below.  Obviously I disagree.

Comment: @tzenes You obviously like to take cheap shots for no apparent reasons; I do not believe there is only one way, but I believe there are better ways. I was simply correcting your Starport section. Also, it is "psionic storm", not "psy[onic] storm"

@Mark He was suggesting Phoenix over Voidrays.

Comment: @Doug I'm not trying to insult you I was merely referencing you had a different answer and that your comment was a reference to that.  You specifically state "You HAVE TO get Voidrays."  Now if I have misrepresented you I apologize. That was not my intention.

Comment: @tzenes When I wrote that answer, it was very much in response to your Protoss > Starport section, thus, I was saying you have to get Voidrays in the Starport because you were saying otherwise. Not the only way in Protoss, but the only way in Starport.

Comment: @Doug my mistake then, I misunderstood you.  I find Phoenix more effective based on the way in which BC attack and how useful they are when the BC are dead.  Now clearly you feel differently, but even so I did make similar suggestions about charging up Voidrays or drawing them out with your faster speed (if upgraded).

Comment: Yamato isn't a reference to anime as far as I know, it was actually the biggest battleship of it's time built by the Japaneese during WWII.  It got sunk pretty quick because US had radar.

Comment: @Torn The Space Battleship Yamato is one of the first successful animes.  In the story line, they dig up the original Battleship Yamato (the one you referenced) and retrofit it to be a spaceship.  You can find more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato

Answer (score 10):

Basically, either a bunch of dedicated air-to-air units (vikings, corruptors) or mass marines/hydras/stalkers.

Race-specific tips:

#### Zerg

- Corruptors are really a hard-counter to battlecruisers, both because of their attack bonus (+ vs massive) and because of their special ability, which is particularly useful when fighting fewer but stronger units. Their high armor is also good against the battlecruiser's attack, which is composed of very high rate of fire but not that high damage.
- Mind control is great against any kind of strong unit, such as battlecruiser.

#### Protoss

- Void rays are useful against beefy units, and work pretty well against battlecruisers, as long as you have enough.
- Phoenixes are actually *not* that good, unless you get a *lot*. They die too quickly, and their relatively low damage means the high armor of the battlecruiser will stop a greater percentage.
- Feedback is pretty good against battlecruisers. Disables their yamato cannon *and* does a great deal of damage.
- Blink is really useful for sniping battlecruisers. Blink the stalkers right beneath them, then target just one at a time. This is why it's important to always accompany battlecruisers with some ground army, to prevent the enemy from getting underneath.

Comment: I have to vote this down for the first sentence. Battlecruisers have very heavy armor so phoenixes do virtually no damage to them. I had a squadron of about 10 phoenixes vs. 4 or 5 battlecruisers and I couldn't even kill one battlecruiser with focus fire. I'm not sure about vikings or corruptors however as I don't play terran or zerg much. You're going to need void rays.

Comment: @Carl: I've addressed this in the 2nd bullet about Protoss: I agree that you need a *lot* of phoenixes. 10 phoenixes are actually less minerals/gas than 4-5 battlecruisers, so it's obvious they won't do; you need significantly more.

Comment: @Oak you're forgetting the scoot and shoot, combined with BC's terrible damage style.

Comment: @Oak I'm aware about the cost difference, but my phoenixes could only do 2 bars of damage to one battlecruiser before dying (about 10% of it's total health). There's some crazy damage reduction of light air vs. battlecruisers going on. Either that or there's some game mechanic that I'm unaware of.

Comment: @Carl fair enough, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Oak changed vote to upvote.

Comment: @Oak Changed to upvote as well.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be giving him the time to get those 12+ Battlecruisers.

So you should press him earlier so he doesn't get that far up the tech tree AND has the time to built that many Battlecruisers

Comment: Not all the matches are played in the game’s sandboxes. Some people plays with infinite resouces and creates huge bases in huge maps.

Comment: Even pro matches have players getting to Battlecruisers (TLO is famous for this), so I think the odds of us mere mortals stopping them is non-existant.

Answer (score -3):

These other answers are now invalid with the release of *Legacy of the Void*. LotV has changed the core fundamentals of Battlecruisers with the removal of their energy requirements and the introduction of the Hyperdrive ability. The Battlecruiser - if accompanied by Marines and Thors - can destroy any army, with the Battlecruisers playing a harassing force.

I currently do not know a good way of fighting them other than forcing their army to split up, which will bring out each troops weaknesses. As Zerg for example, having Lurkers attack one side with Mutalisks attacking another and Roach/Zergling/Hydra attacking a 3rd front.

Comment: you should probably explain how *"the removal of battle cruisers energy requirements and its new ability hyperdrive"* invalidates any of the answers already posted rather than just saying that and posting a lackluster solution

Comment: So your strategy is to either split the army up or get a surround on them? Whilst both good tactics, a good player will avoid the former and should know how to focus down the latter and/or prevent the surround in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

First of all, I do not understand why people are telling you, "You should not give him that much time to build 12 Battlecruisers in the first place". That is clearly not a solution to fighting Battlecruisers.

For Protoss players up against Battlecruisers, Phoenixes **CANNOT** take on Battlecruisers. Go try it, they will get *demolished*. **You HAVE TO get Voidrays** against Battlecruisers. Voidrays were made for this reason. The charge is the only thing that can drop their HP and storm does not work effectively on mech units. Also, a side note, you can charge your Voidrays before you enter a battle by attacking a rock or even your own structures (if you are desperate).

You can also get Mothership with Carriers and Voidrays as well. If you do, do not worry about letting your mothership die. While it is tanking, you can destroy half of your opponents fleet by then.

Basically, nothing other than Protoss air (Voidrays, Carriers, Mothership) can take on Battlecruisers. I should say, not as well. If you find yourself stuck in a Gateway build, then you should try out tzene's strategy. Otherwise, you should go air against Battlecruisers.

However, if you run into a situation where he has the superior army then you can always aim for a base race; Avoid his army and wait until he attacks, so you can attack his base without him defending.

Comment: @Dough It is strange how you tell him its impossible to prevent someone from building Battlecruisers, but then require he build Voidrays.  I'm not saying Voidrays aren't powerful, just that this stand point seems hypocritical.  Perhaps if you could elaborate on how he should produce these Voidrays when he suddenly finds himself against 12 BC?  Also, why do you say storm is not effective against mech?  It does identical damage to mech and bio.  Also, I think you mean demolished not diminished.

Comment: I agree with @tzenes Not sure what point you are trying to make @Doug.  With proper scouting you will see he is going BC and if you don't already have Stargates at this point then you should work with what you got.  High Templars are very effective with an army of stalkers against BC.  Feedback + Storm with stalker focus fire will destroy a group of BC quickly.  You need good micro for this to work as well so you can blink out the stalker that is taking damage, not the whole group of stalkers.  It helps to hold down alt so you can see their health bars and select the ones losing their shields.

Comment: I've seen stalkers effectively take on battlecruisers, especially when blink was used in a smart way.

Comment: @tzenes Go try to storm mech, their health does not drop like bio units do because they have way more HP. He was asking for a solution for fighting against 12 Battlecruisers yet people focused on preventing it rather than battling it. Look, if you suddenly find yourself against 12 BC then you would have to stick with what you have, but that is not the case. He asked "How should [he] prepare [his] army...". Now, you also suggested him to use Phoenixes and said that Voidrays are LESS useful while it is the contrary. And yes, I did mean demolish, thank you.

Comment: Don't downvote an answer just because it's in competition with yours. This answer is more correct than the above answers. Psi storm indeed does very little damage to heavily armored units and phoenix do almost zero damage at all to battlecruisers. Void rays are the real counter, but you should try to charge them up before engaging the BC's.

Comment: @Doug not only have I stormed mech, but I've done so with large success.  Now, maybe its just because I play in Diamond, but I rarely change my overall strategy based on something like Battlecruisers, I always work with what I have.  I may build more Stalkers than I would otherwise, or a few extra Templar, but I'm not going to throw down 3 Starports and hope to power out Voidrays in time.

Comment: @tzenes I respect you for playing in Diamond, but you must agree at some extent that getting Voidrays are much better than Stalkers. Especially when you are preparing against an opponent "who has 12+ battlecruisers."

Comment: @Doug I agree they are better at killing the BC than the Stalker is.  I don't agree they're better to get.  If I'm in a 4 gate (or possibly 6 gate + robo or starport) situation and I'm trying to attack someone running on 12 BC, I'm not going to throw down 3 more Starports, and Chronoboost Voidrays, because the reality is they'll never arrive in time.  In that situation I'd push with Stalker/Templar (as WhiteRa does making them run through Storms and Blinking back).

Comment: What you say is true (in that situation), but the question was not in that situation and how should he prepare his army meaning he has the time for the switch. Also, duckloadRa is not the best, if you have been keeping up.

Comment: @Doug I don't have another good example of someone having to react to 10+ BC out of a 4 Gate opening.  He said he's attacking someone who has 12 BC.  Not someone who is building BC.  This implies time, but not a ton of time.  I firmly believe thinking "Wouldn't it be great if I had X," is a harmful thought pattern.

Comment: @tzenes But you are only assuming he is coming out of a 4 Gate opening. He also used the word prepare which implies pre-attack which has a lot of time, especially when his opponent is building Battlecruisers.

Comment: @tzene I updated my answer to include your Gateway situation

Comment: @Doug I'm not assuming anything, that's why I have 3 different strategies listed there.  Now I read prepare to mean he has sometime, but not forever.  If he has some how scouted BC and he now has to react, that should mean he's playing catchup and without a superior economy, won't have enough Voidrays.  Maybe at this point we should change this question to CW and combine answers?

Comment: Just a note about Diamond league. If I can get into Diamond league, then anyone who is slightly above average can as well. I never played Starcraft 1, so the matching/ranking system is definitely flawed if I can be rank 2. Very often it puts me against lesser skilled players (i.e. massing only marines without even walling off). So I don't see "I'm in diamond league" as a good measure of credibility.

Comment: @Carl don't see what league any of us are in as being relevant information, but he asked and I saw no harm in answering.  What's more, I didn't down vote this answer, I just disagree with parts of it, most specifically the terms "cannot" and "have to."  I believe Phoenix can stop BC (as I have) and that Voidrays are not the only answer.