# As Protoss, how can I counter mass Battlecruisers in PvT?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

What to do against Terran opponents who go for mass Battlecruisers?

Most skytoss units seem to be garbage at that point. Are Archons at all viable in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the exact same problem as zerg. I knew that corruptors were the hard counter to BC, but I hated going spire. I also checked the forums like you did and found this one.

[What's the best counter strategy against battlecruisers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/whats-the-best-counter-strategy-against-battlecruisers/4805#4805)

Which has some great answers. But trust me the solution I found works with every race, not just zerg. The best answer I found that worked for me, I had to find with practice. I will explain what I mean.

I was gold I believe, when I started getting crushed by Battlecruisers. And I got to this phase where I *played* against terrans just so I can *try* to stop BC's. And then I realised something.

Your opponent can't *beat you* with Battlecruisers if they *don't have* battlecruisers. Battlecruisers might be a lot of things, but they are not cheap. And I noticed something in the behavior of all my BC opponents. They were *waiting* for something. They were waiting to gather enough resources for the BC! And this is when I found my solution.

1. If you see a small army compared to yours or a lack of one, attack with whatever you have (I would use warpgate units) and aim for his mineral lines. Even if he is not going for BC's, he is either not spending his money or doing some shenanigans.
2. If somehow, he still gets up to 2-3 BC's, built some stalkers/void rays to defend against them, but do not waste your money!

This is basically how I beat Battlecruisers in my games.

I hope this helps and remember, do not get paranoid that every terran goes for battlecruisers. This also played a huge mistake in my games.

Answer (score 1):

Early game, go for stalkers. Keep them around your mineral lines and protect your probes. It's true, you cannot do much at this stage if the BCs just teleport away but your priority should be to gather resources to build up the counter army. Build shield batteries to assist your stalkers.

After the 10 min. mark replace those stalkers with Archons.

Once you've got three bases, go for Mass tempests. Use revelation to scout ahead and hallucinations to increase the survivability of your tempests. Your tempests will undoubtedly outrange his BCs and winning should be fairly easy with this deathball if your macro is good enough.

Comment: Tempests are very expensive and are inferior to Void Rays, i don't think Tempest is a good idea https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzDGyRQzAKc

Answer (score 1):

If you need a direct counter, mass void ray will beat mass BC, but there is another consideration you should make here.

It takes a lot of time and a lot of resources to get to the stage of *mass* battlecruiser, there is a stage when their investments make them vulnerable to attack.

Exploit this window. Apply pressure to your opponent, do not let them expand, tech and mass without resistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Void Rays, they can focus on each BC and deal huge damage over time. They are made for this type of situations, if stacked correctly they should win again BC's. Even better if they are backed up by Hight Templars with Psy Storm, they can be transformed into Archons later. Even batter if you can add a Mothership.

[BC vs Void Rays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N46TlynXlHk)

Comment: I dont see them using Yamato cannon in that video, also if it gets too hairy, Terran can just jump his BCs.

Comment: Actually Void Rays can attack while they move. Yamato is better against static targets/buildings because it shoots far. Not so good in combat, it has a huge cooldown time and you have a lot until it shoots, also you have to aim at each Void Ray and the DPS, with delay and wait time and all, it is not bigger than the standard attack mode.

Comment: And you can Yamato something that has low health already, wasting your charge and energy.